# jQuery $.ajax post doesn't posts any data to ASP page

Tags: jquery, post, asp-classic

This is the code:

Html of the form:

```
<div id="contact_form">
<h1>Contact us</h1>
<p>Please use the form below to send us a message.</p>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return sendContact();" action="sendContact.asp">
<p><label for="name" id="lname">Full name:</label>
<input type="text" class="text" name="name" id="name" onfocus="input_focus('name');" onblur="input_blur('name');" /></p>
<p><label for="email" id="lemail">Email address:</label>
<input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email" onfocus="input_focus('email');" onblur="input_blur('email');" /></p>
<div class="x"></div>
<p class="error" id="email-error">You must enter your email address.</p>
<p><label for="category" id="lcategory">Category:</label>
<select name="category" id="category" onfocus="input_focus('category');"     onblur="input_blur('category');">
<option value="software">Software</option>
<option value="hardwae">Hardware</option>
<option value="consulting">Consulting</option>
<option value="resources">Resources</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="message" id="lmessage">Message:</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message" onfocus="input_focus('message');"     onblur="input_blur('message');"></textarea></p>
<div class="x"></div>
<p class="error" id="message-error">You must enter your message.</p>
<p><label for="captcha" id="lcaptcha"></label>
<input type="text" class="text" name="captcha" id="captcha"     onfocus="input_focus('captcha');" onblur="input_blur('captcha');" /></p>
<div class="x"></div>
<p class="error" id="captcha-error">Are you shure about your calculations?</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
generate_captcha('lcaptcha');
</script>
<div class="x"></div>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="send_contact" value="Send" />
</form>
<span id="contact-back">or you can <a href="index.html" class="read-more">Go back</a</span>
</div>
<div id="message_sent" style="display:none;">
<h1>Your message has been sent</h1>
<p>We'll contact you in a shortest possible time.</p>
<p>You can now <a href="index.html" class="read-more">go back</a> to home page.</p>
</div>    
</div>
```

this is the js which makes the post (a part of the sendContact() function):

```
     var data = $("#contact_form > form").serialize();
```

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sendContact.asp",
  global: false,
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  data: data,
  dataType: "text",
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  error:function () { 
   alert('AJAX Connectivity Error');}, 
  success: function(msg){
  }
});

$("#contact_form").fadeOut(1000, function() {
  $("#message_sent").slideDown(500);
 });

return false;
}

And this is the code which should catch the querystring "sendContact.asp":

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Response.Buffer = False 
Response.CacheControl = "No-cache"
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Set Fso = server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SendContact = Fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("\contact.txt"), ForAppending, True, -1)
SendContact.WriteLine "Consulta sobre: "&Request("category")&", timestamp: "&Now()&""
SendContact.WriteLine "IP:"&Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")&""
SendContact.WriteLine "Nombre: "&Request("name")&""
SendContact.WriteLine "E-mail: "&Request("email")&""
SendContact.WriteLine "Mensaje: "&Request("message")&""
SendContact.WriteBlankLines 2
SendContact.Close
%>
```

When the information is sent with the form everything looks to be correct, but any data is posted to "senContact.asp" and one blank space is written into the fields of "contact.txt", except the timestamp and the remote ip. I've also tried to do the request "Request.Querystring("id")" but resulst were the same.

Thank you for tour help

Comment: Well, this calls for basic debugging. Starting with `data` - does it contain anything? Try `console.log(data)` to find out

Comment: data is sent correctly, i think that the problem could be in the ASP page.

Comment: i replicated your code and it works just fine.. Two things come in mind. a) Could it be that one page is authenticated and the other is not ? b) Do you use any component that reads binary data submitted ? because i recall that most of those somehow mess with the posted data and usually create a wrapper object to provide that info.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is old question, I am sending its possible answer.

Before binding each POST parameter, you can use `escape` function what encodes the variables and converts the blanks and any other 'unsafe' character for URL usage.

For quick example (I've just used one parameter here. You can add other parameters accordingly):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sendContact.asp",
  global: false,
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  data: "name=" + escape(document.getElementById("name").value),
  dataType: "text",
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  error:function () { 
   alert('AJAX Connectivity Error');}, 
  success: function(msg){
  }
});
```

Hope that it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Content type is by default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the data is always sent as `utf-8`.

Not sure if this line

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

should contain both .. try without it in case it messes the data being send

---

**Original answer proven wrong by T.J. Crowder**

You are using the `POST` method to send the data so you need to read them with `request.form("..")`

So change all your `request("..")` to `request.form("..")`

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: No, in ASP, `Request("x")` gets the "x" variable from either the `GET` or `POST` data, wherever it finds it. You *can* be more specific (`Request.Form("x")` for `POST`), but you don't have to be.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, you are correct.. just the power of doing something the same way, makes you forget the alternatives..

Answer (score 0):

**Two thoughts:**

#### Validation

You have an unclosed `</a` tag on this line (you may have to scroll the code to the right a bit):

```
<span id="contact-back">or you can <a href="index.html" class="read-more">Go back</a</span>
<!--                                                                                ^-- here -->
```

The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) can help with that kind of thing. Invalid markup can really waste your time. :-) But it may well be a red herring here. (The validator also says there's an extra `</div>`, but I suspect that's just an artifact of copy-and-paste.)

#### Synchronous Ajax in a Submit Handler

I wouldn't try to issue a *synchronous* Ajax request from within the form submit handler, it just seems like you're asking for trouble.

I'd try letting the event handler complete, and *then* sending the form:

```
function sendContact() {
    var data = $("#contact_form > form").serialize();

    setTimeout(sendViaAjax, 0);
    return false;

    function sendViaAjax() {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "sendContact.asp",
          global: false,
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
          data: data,
          dataType: "text",
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          error:function () { 
              alert('AJAX Connectivity Error');
          }, 
          success: function(msg){
          }
        });

        $("#contact_form").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $("#message_sent").slideDown(500);
        });
    }
}
```

---

Off-topic, but I'd strongly recommend avoiding synchronous Ajax requests on the main UI thread. (Synchronous Ajax in a [web worker](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), fine.) There's no need for them, and they lock up the browser something fierce (particularly IE, but all of them to varying degrees).

Comment: The unclosed link was a mistake pasting here the code, I've checked all tags. I made the request to be synchronous only to investigate, but wether synchronous or asynchronous it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used an app like fiddler to look at the traffic going to that page to make sure the data is actually being posted?  Also move the fading out of the form and showing of the div into the success handler, you only want that to run on a successful ajax request.